# Search for new line position in a VB.NET string variable using InStr

Tags: vb.net, search, string, newline

I have an application in VB.NET which gets string data from the database. This string has data which looks as below:

> "This is the update:
>   I have an issue with the application"

I need only part of the data, that comes after the new line i.e. "I have an issue with the application".

For this I am trying to search the position using [InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) where the string has data in a new line. I tried many options, but they don't work.

I used "vbCrLf", Chr(13), "\r\n", "\n", "`<br/>`", Environment.NewLine, but none of them work.

How can I get the data I need?

Comment: did you quote vbCrLf? it should be used withoud quoutes.

Answer (score 2):

The newline character can be represented either by just a newline character (`Chr(10)`) or by a carriage return/linefeed pair (`Chr(13) + Chr(10)`). Depending on the source of the data this may of course vary. One way to achieve this is to make a string split on those two characters with the option to remove empty elements, throw away the first one and join the others together with newlines in between them:

```
ReadOnly separators As Char() = New Char() {Chr(10), Chr(13)}
Private Function StripFirstLine(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim parts() As String = input.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    If parts.Length > 1 Then
        Return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, parts, 1, parts.Length - 1)
    Else
        Return input
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: It't CR+LF (Char(13) + Char(10)), not the other way around.

Comment: @Guffa: you are right of course; flipped it around. Must be the heat.

Comment: In vb.net, you can also use the individual vbCr and vbLf constants, rather than having to call the Chr() function.

Answer (score 2):

Use vbCrLf and not "vbCrLf"

It may also be that you have only line feeds or only carrige returns so using Chr(10) and Chr(13) may also be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'm adding much to this discussion but for what it's worth... you can also use "ControlChars" as in "ControlChars.CrLf".

[ControlChars @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz4eweb8.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This script returns the string in lines and then add it to a listbox:

```
    Dim fileContents As String
    fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("d:\a.txt")
    TextBox2.Text = fileContents
    Dim a As Integer = 1

    For i = 1 To fileContents.Length
        Dim xx As String = Mid(fileContents, i, 1)
        If xx = Chr(10) Then
            If Mid(fileContents, i - 1, 1) = Chr(13) Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(Mid(fileContents, a, (i - a) - 1))
                a = i
            End If
        End If
    Next
```